# How use the API Mailgun-PHP in Google App Engine (PHP)?

Tags: google-app-engine, curl, mailgun

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Common\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'The PHP cURL extension must be installed to use Guzzle.'

How install PHP cURL in GAE?

Comment: I don't think you can install cURL in GAE but you can always use urlfetch: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use curl on google app engine, Mailgun also does not support javascript requests for security reasons